# How to write URL For multiple Slug

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

**here is my path**

```
path('<slug:category_slug>/<slug:city_slug>/<slug:slug_text>/', views.category_view_detail,
         name='post_detail'),
```

**how to write URL for this example {% url 'post_delete' posts.slug %} but i want to add all three slug inside the URL how to do something like this...
({% url 'post_detail' posts.category posts.city posts.slug %})
but this not work..**

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not working because you are referring to a different URL pattern name
You are using `post_delete` the one in the code is `post_detail`

```py
{% url 'post_detail' posts.slug posts.city posts.slug %}
# or
{% url 'post_detail' category_slug=posts.category city_slug=posts.city slug_text=posts.slug %}
```

Comment: i understood, Thank you for helping.